# Bootstrap 4 jquery (not slim version) bugs

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estou com um projeto web que fizeram o front utilizando o BT4. Nos docs do BT4 é apresentada a CDN do jquery.slim como necessária.

Eu gostaria de utilizar a função $.ajax do jquery, mas ela não está disponível na versão slim do jquery.

O BT4 com a versão normal do jquery apresenta alguns bugs como nas classes navbar.

Alguém já passou por isso e teve alguma solução simples? (eu não queria ter que montar a estrutura de chamadas ajax manualmente)

Comment: Cara vc tem alguma referencia desses bugs da navbar com a versão completa do jquey? eu nunca tinha ouvido falar disso...

Comment: Não entendo muitos das classes do bootstrap, preciso ver na segunda se utilizaram elas corretamente.

Comment: Ao trocar a versão do jquery pelo meu ver o menu dropdown do layout ficou estranho, acredito que com um timeout nos efeitos de abrir e fechar. Se eu passar pelos hovers das opcoes elas vão abrindo antes outras estarem fechadas virando a bagunça.

Comment: O dev do front dissse q usou apenas o navbar do bootstrap 4 e eu apenas troquei a versão do jquery.

Comment: O dev do front tinha colocado uma classe com efeito slow utilizando o jquery, na versão slim nao funcionava. Quando eu trocava a versão o hover do menu ficava horrível.

Comment: O dev do front tinha colocado uma classe com efeito slow utilizando o jquery, na versão slim nao funcionava. Quando eu trocava a versão o hover do menu ficava horrível. Não era nenhum bug. Agradeço pelo auxílio.